# TypeScript import from

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

All:

When I read "Angular2 5mins start"-Tutorial, the first syntax confuses me:

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

I wonder where can I find this syntax from TypeScript (I only find import, but not import...from)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Syntax was added in ES6 for JavaScript, here is the complete list and explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

> import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";

... is the one you found in your Tutorial.

- **member, memberN** Name of the exported members to be imported.
- **module-name** The name of the module to import. This is a file name.

Note that this ES6-JavaScript feature is not supported in any Browser as of today. But TypeScript / AngularJS will deal with it.

---

There was no such syntax in the original TypeScript.
Here is the TyepScript Handbook about `import`: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-going-external

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I read that handbook, but no finding about import...from syntax.So that Angular2 Typescript tutorial actually mix Typescript and ES6?

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is for ES2015, also known as ES6. Basically, it lets you decide what to import from the external files. See [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) or [the standard itself](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports) if you need some light reading.

Comment: Thanks. There are two extra questions about AngularJS2, should I pick Angular2 as start or React.js, for either of them, I am pretty new.

Comment: Well, that's a different question :). Angular 2 is current in "alpha" status, so I would be hesitant to use it as the basis for an application seeing production sooner than a year out.